# Cannot read json into json to struct

Tags: json, rest, go, request, crud

I reading put request to struct

I have a product struct where exist the specifications struct. And i cannot read in this request:

`

```
{
    "id": "4de5951b-c7ef-462b-83af-6402cc3c0beb",
    "name": "Product 1",
    "description": "Description 1",
    "image_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "taste_id": "896c8032-d0f8-4f54-96dd-7173f0e207c6",
    "category_id": "d048b017-f243-46b8-a3d3-14f2642db4e0",
    "price": "130",
    "specifications": {
        "size": "20",
        "color": "white"
    },
    "created_at": "2023-07-20T10:23:58.254118+03:00",
    "updated_at": null
}
```

And writes this:

```
{
    "product": {
        "id": "",
        "name": "Product 1",
        "description": "Description 1",
        "image_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "taste_id": "896c8032-d0f8-4f54-96dd-7173f0e207c6",
        "category_id": "d048b017-f243-46b8-a3d3-14f2642db4e0",
        "price": "130",
        "specifications": {},
        "created_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "updated_at": null
    }
}
```

My code:

```
type createProductInput struct {
    Name           string                `json:"name"`
    Description    string                `json:"description"`
    TasteID        string                `json:"taste_id"`
    CategoryID     string                `json:"category_id"`
    Price          string                `json:"price"`
    Specifications entity.Specifications `json:"specifications"`
    ImageID        string                `json:"image_id"`
}

func (h *Handler) UpdateProduct(c *gin.Context) {
    var input createProductInput

    if err := c.BindJSON(&input); err != nil {
        newErrorResponse(c, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }

    if input.ImageID == "" {
        input.ImageID = NULLUUID
    }

    fmt.Println(input.Specifications) // this line write {}

    err := h.service.Product.Update(c.Request.Context(), entity.Product{
        Name:           input.Name,
        Description:    input.Description,
        TasteID:        input.TasteID,
        CategoryID:     input.CategoryID,
        Price:          input.Price,
        Specifications: input.Specifications,
        ImageID:        &input.ImageID,
    }, c.Param("id"))
    if err != nil {
        newErrorResponse(c, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, CreateProductResponse{
        Product: entity.Product{
            Name:           input.Name,
            Description:    input.Description,
            TasteID:        input.TasteID,
            CategoryID:     input.CategoryID,
            Price:          input.Price,
            Specifications: input.Specifications,
            ImageID:        &input.ImageID,
        },
    })
}
```

`

I havent errors and warnings. Just tried write just string like type to product struct.

My last try was replace string type in the strict to []bytes.

I ask for help please  who can do it.